# .net 3.5 SP1 Bootstrapper not found for Setup

Tags: installation, .net-3.5, bootstrapping

I am getting a warning when trying to include the .net 3.5 sp1 prerequisite for my setup project.  The warning states Prerequisite could not found for bootstrapping.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues)

Answer (score 3):

I followed the directions in 2.3.1.1 Enable Samesite for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper package  and now everything works perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, having had the same issue as the creator Ryan, I solved my delima by folling these steps:

Update the Package Data

Open the [Program Files]\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 folder or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 on x64 operating systems 
Edit the Product.xml file in Notepad. 
Paste the following into the < PackageFiles > element:

```
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg.exe"/>
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_x64.exe"/>
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_ia64.exe"/>
```

Find the element for `< PackageFile Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-x86-en-US.exe"` and change the PublicKey value to: `3082010A0282010100A2DB0A8DCFC2C1499BCDAA3A34AD23596BDB6CBE2122B794C8EAAEBFC6D526C232118BBCDA5D2CFB36561E152BAE8F0DDD14A36E284C7F163F41AC8D40B146880DD98194AD9706D05744765CEAF1FC0EE27F74A333CB74E5EFE361A17E03B745FFD53E12D5B0CA5E0DD07BF2B7130DFC606A2885758CB7ADBC85E817B490BEF516B6625DED11DF3AEE215B8BAF8073C345E3958977609BE7AD77C1378D33142F13DB62C9AE1AA94F9867ADD420393071E08D6746E2C61CF40D5074412FE805246A216B49B092C4B239C742A56D5C184AAB8FD78E833E780A47D8A4B28423C3E2F27B66B14A74BD26414B9C6114604E30C882F3D00B707CEE554D77D2085576810203010001` 
Find the element for < PackageFile Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-amd64-en-US.exe" and change the PublicKey value to the same as in step 4 above 
Save the product.xml file

Download and Extract the Core Installation Files

Navigate to the following URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=118080 
Download the dotNetFx35.exe file to your local disk. 
Open a Command Prompt window and change to the directory to which you downloaded dotNetFx35.exe. 
At the command prompt, type: 
dotNetFx35.exe /x:. 
This will extract the Framework files to a folder named “WCU” in the current directory. 
Copy the contents of the WCU\dotNetFramework folder and paste them in the %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 folder (%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 on x64 operating systems). Note: Do not copy the WCU\dotNetFramework folder itself. There should be 5 folders under the WCU folder, and each of these should now appear in the DotNetFx35SP1 folder. The folder structure should resemble the following:
o DotNetFx35SP1 (folder) 
dotNetFX20 (folder 
dotNetFX30 (folder) 
dotNetFX35 (folder) 
dotNetMSP (folder) 
TOOLS folder) 
en (or some other localized folder) 
dotNetFx35setup.exe (file)

You may now delete the files and folders you downloaded and extracted in steps 2 and 4.

Found at [Microsoft Solutions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm#General%20Issues)

Comment: What is weird is I installed VS 2008 with SP1 but I don't have the DotNetFx35SP1 folder in the path mentioned in the SameSite section of that doc, I just have the the DotNetFX35 folder so I am missing the Product.xml file for 3.5 SP1, I wondering if just copying the 3.5 Product.xml file will be ok, which is what I did, I created a DotNetFx35SP1 folder and extracted the files like mentioned in the Samesite section to this dir.

Comment: Because I didn't have the DotNetFx35SP1 folder I had no Product.xml file to modify, any idea where I can get one? I also have no lang folder either because I didn't have that folder which is odd considering I installed the VS2008 iso with SP1. So my problem right now is VS 2008 will not pick up that bootstrapper dir I created.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2015, here is a **very simple solution** (including some Michael Eakins answer):

1. Download the installer here:
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=118080
2. Extract / open with 7zip or Winrar and extract the contence to a folder
3. Copy/move everything under the extracted folder "wcu\dotNetFramework" path to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio      4.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1

4. Publish in VS2015