# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project warning "Could Not find prerequisite ".Net Framework 3.5 SP1"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

In an inherited Visual Studio 2008 setup project I have a "Launch Conditions" for ".Net Framework".

Properties Windows for condition ".Net Framework":

(Name)        .Net Framework

InstallUrl    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76617

Message       [VSDNETMSG]

Verison        3.5.30729

On doing a build I get the following warning:

Could not find prerequisite ".NET Framework 3.5 SP1' in path "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\'"

I have read numerous posts (such as [.net 3.5 SP1 Bootstrapper not found for Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221913/net-3-5-sp1-bootstrapper-not-found-for-setup)) on this issue and the section "2.3.1.1 Enable Samesite for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper package" of "Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Readme".

All solutions involve the directory "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\DotNetFx35SP1". The problem, I do not have this directory. I do not see "Microsoft .Net 3.5 SP1 in" the "Programs and Features" window either. I do see "Microsoft .Net Compact Framework 3.5" listed.

Therefore, I conclude that I need to install ".Net 3.5 SP1". I download "Net 3.5 SP1" from "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22". I attempt to run the installer and after double-clicking and selecting run, nothing happens.

I then use the "netfx_setupverifier.exe" and it validates successfully for ".Net 3.5 SP1".

In addition, the "InstallUrl" property no longer links to an appropriate page.

So, I have no idea how to resolve the warning to ensure a user installing the application has the appropriate version of the ".Net framework" and if they do not, install the .Net version automatically.

Should I just remove this launch condition due to the fact that ".Net 3.5 SP1" should already be part of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Those paths contain the clue - many of the prerequisites for setup projects are installed by the Windows SDK, the 6.0a version in this case. It's my understanding that the 6.1 SDK is an update to 6.0a so that one will work also. It's possible that the installation of VS 2008 did not select any options related to the SDK and Redistributables, because I believe the 6.0a SDK shipped with VS 2008, or this may be what you need, 6.1:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310